# Sinon Stub for AWS X-Ray calls

Tags: sinon, aws-sdk-js, aws-sdk-nodejs

I'm trying to set stubs for AWS X-Ray calls to unit-test NodeJS Lambdas outside of AWS.

I have the code below in my lambda. How can I use sinon to stub out the calls to the AWSXRay API shown below? The getSegment() call has to be stubbed, then "chained" so I can then call addNewSubSegment(parm)?

```
const AWSXRay = require('aws-xray-sdk-core');
...

const rootSubSegment = AWSXRay.getSegment().addNewSubsegment("RootSubSegment");
rootSubSegment.addAnnotation("MyAnnotationKey", "MyAnnotationData");
rootSubSegment.addMetadata("MyMetaDataKey", "MyMetaData");

const s3SubSegment = AWSXRay.getSegment().addNewSubsegment("Do S3 Stuff");
...
s3SubSegment.close();

rootSubSegment.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to stub `getSegment` to return an object that has a stubbed `addNewSubsegment` property.

It looks like your code runs as soon as it is required, so you need to make sure your stub is in place before requiring your code in the test.

Here is a working example test to get you started:

```js
const AWSXRay = require('aws-xray-sdk-core');
const sinon = require('sinon');

describe('code', () => {
  it('should add subsegments', () => {
    const getSegmentStub = sinon.stub(AWSXRay, 'getSegment');
    const addNewSubsegmentStub = sinon.stub();
    getSegmentStub.returns({ addNewSubsegment: addNewSubsegmentStub });
    const rootSubSegmentMock = {
      addAnnotation: sinon.spy(),
      addMetadata: sinon.spy(),
      close: sinon.spy()
    }
    const s3SubSegmentMock = {
      close: sinon.spy()
    }
    addNewSubsegmentStub.onFirstCall().returns(rootSubSegmentMock);
    addNewSubsegmentStub.onSecondCall().returns(s3SubSegmentMock);

    require('[path to your code]');  // <= now require the code to run it

    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(addNewSubsegmentStub.firstCall, 'RootSubSegment');  // Success!
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(addNewSubsegmentStub.secondCall, 'Do S3 Stuff');  // Success!
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(rootSubSegmentMock.addAnnotation, 'MyAnnotationKey', 'MyAnnotationData');  // Success!
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(rootSubSegmentMock.addMetadata, 'MyMetaDataKey', 'MyMetaData');  // Success!
    sinon.assert.called(s3SubSegmentMock.close);  // Success!
    sinon.assert.called(rootSubSegmentMock.close);  // Success!
  })
})
```